# andThen with square brackets and underscore in Scala function

Tags: scala

I have two functions

```
val mul3 = 3*(_: Double)
val pow2 = (x: Double) => x*x
```

What I don't understand how it works at all is this:

```
println((pow2.andThen[Double] _ )(mul3)(5))
```

1) I thought `andThen` operates with results of the function to the left, but here it is `[Double] _` - what is this? (I was expecting something like `pow2 andThen mul3`)
2) Why is `mul3` passed to `pow2` if `pow2` expects `Double`? (`mul3(pow2)` gives an error)
3) What is being passed to `pow2`? Is it `mul3` or 15?
4) What does `.` mean?

[scala fiddle](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/W3zmjxU1SPqhtT1Daa35vQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets go step by step.

```
val mul3 = 3*(_: Double)
```

Is a **Function** from a **Double** to another **Double**. Thus, is type is `Function1[Double, Double]`.
The same applies to:

```
val pow2 = (x: Double) => x*x
```

Now, remember that in Scala, everything is an *object*. And that there are not *operators*, only *methods*. So:

```
pow2.andThen[Double]
```

Is calling the `andThen` on [*method*](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html#andThen[A](g:R=%3EA):T1=%3EA) on the **Function1** *class*.
As you can see on the scaldoc, that method receives another function. Also, it is parametric in the return type of the second function, which determines the return type of the composed function that is returned.
So the `[Double]` part is just specifying that type.

```
pow2.andThen[Double] _
```

Is using the underscore syntax to create another function.
The above line is equivalent to:

```
f => pow2.andThen[Double](f)
```

So, it is creating a **function** that takes another **function** as input, and returns another **function**. The resulting function will call `pow2` first and then call the function passed as the argument.
Thus, it is of type `Function1[Function1[Double, Double], Function[Double, Double]]`.

Then

```
(pow2.andThen[Double] _ )(mul3)
```

Is passing `mul3` as the argument of that **function**, returning a final **function** *(`Function1[Double, Doule]`)* that calls `pow2` first and pass the result to `mul3`.

Finally

```
(pow2.andThen[Double] _ )(mul3)(5)
```

Is calling the resulting **function** with `5` as is input.
After substitution, the code is equivalent to:

```
x => mul3(pow2(x))
x => 3 * (x * x)
5 => 3 * (x * x)
3 * (5 * 5)
75.0
```

---

Side note, IMHO, that code is very cryptic and far for what I would call idiomatic in Scala.

Comment: Isn't `mul3` have a type `Function1[Double]` rather than `Function1[Double, Double]`?

Comment: @techkuz You can not have a `Fuction1[X]`. A **function** is parametrized for their _inputs_ & _output_. `Function1` means it is a function of a single argument. Thus, the first **Double*: is for the input, the second is for the output. _- `Function1[X, Y] === X => Y`.